# Rails access current GET page parameters from url using coffee

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I am making changes to a section of an app that uses a js coffee script to navigate to a different page of the site. I would like to append the current get request to the new url.

Is there an easy way of accessing the get request in the coffee script?

I know in javascript you can use window.location to get the full url, but how do you do it in coffeescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the following code

```
paramValue = (name) ->
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]")
  regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"
  regex = new RegExp(regexS)
  results = regex.exec(window.location.href)
  unless results?
    ""
  else
    results[1]
```

The argument to the method is the name of the param of the param whose value you require. It will return the corresponding value of that particular url

`window.location.href` will return the URL of the current page